# SSRS Portrait/Landscape, Page numbers & TOC

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm planning to use .NET / SQL Server / SSRS to migrate an old application.

I've just started migrating the report over to SSRS (SQL Server 2012) and have bumped into a few limitations. I've searched the internet and found a few workarounds for them, but when combining them all it seems I've hit a brick wall.

So: 
1. The report has both landscape and portrait 
2. The report has a table of contents with page numbers 
3. The footer has the page number of the report

Now I have read that the only way to get around the #1 limitation is to have multiple reports (some portrait and some landscape) and combine the PDFs later on using something like iTextSharp (not a problem). However, this will then break #2 and #3 as page numbers will reset for each new report.

Is there a way to handle this? I haven't even worked out how to do #2 yet (as there is nothing out of the box) but the concept remains the same.

I would have thought this was basic reporting functionality, but obviously not!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't easily handle point #2 if you have object that could span over multiple pages depending on data, i.e. `Tablix`... so 99% of the reports! ;)

Comment: Hmm yeah, just looking into iTextSharp and it says you can create page numbers, so I may be able to generate the TOC using that. I guess I might be able to split out each report, generate them as a PDF and then use iTextSharp to merge them all, put in page numbers & add in a TOC.